# Using Contains how to search for more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
select * from Person where CONTAINS((fName,sName),'John AND Doe')
```

So I am trying to search for John Doe but I get that I cannot use AND here (just showing my chain of thought) so how can I search for John in the fName and Doe in the sName ? But I don't want to use "Contains" twice like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
WHERE CONTAINS((fName), 'John')
AND CONTAINS((sName), 'Doe');
```

Since we can have

> (fName,sName)

but I cannot use

> 'John','Doe'/'John' AND 'Doe'

Comment: Why do you think you would hit the database twice?

Comment: How is that hitting the database twice?  You have one SQL statement which the engine will optimize the best it can to obtain the desired results.  IT queries two separate columns and filters for such data.  That's exactly what it should do...

Comment: So I am just told to make it so that it doesn't hit twice, but isn't there a way to use the query without using 2 Contains ?

Comment: Have you created a fulltext index on fName and sName ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha yes I have it works on the 2nd query but I don't want to use 2 Contains, if that is even possible

Comment: @ApolloKS09 I don't have SQL Server test environment, but please can you follow the steps on [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91ccdffe7c57cca13291bf07b72dcaae), maybe it might help

Comment: @ErgestBasha nope it still returns nothing, so I want to more the AND in the John AND Doe, because it is searching for John Doe where only John is in the fName, I am not sure if we can change the position, I have tried a bunch of stuff that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
WHERE CONTAINS((fName), 'John')
AND CONTAINS((sName), 'Doe');
```

can't compile because CONTAINS returns a number, not a boolean.

It shall respond,on oracle, with this kind of error

```
ORA-00920: opérateur relationnel non valide
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
```

(the relational operator error's cause is not the `AND`'s existence, it's because you try to `AND` two numbers)

What do you intend to do? If you want to select the line in the person table whose `fName` columns contains the substring `John` and whose `sName` column contains the substring `Doe`, you may use the `like` operator, which uses `%` as a wildcard.

```
SELECT * FROM Person
WHERE fName LIKE '%John%'
and sName LIKE '%Doe%'
```

I don't practice much the CONTAINS method, but if you desire to use it, according to documentation, you should use something like

```
SELECT * FROM Person
WHERE CONTAINS(fName, 'John') > 0
and CONTAINS(sName,'Doe') > 0
```

If you really don't want to use the `AND` operator (for whatever obscure reason like proving a sql injection filter is bad), you can use this trick : compare a concatenation of the 2 columns and the `like` operator like so

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
WHERE fName || sName like '%John%Doe%';
```

but this last trick will also match the line where `fname` is `John Doe` and `sName` is `Jean-Michel` :)

Comment: I really did want to use the LIKE method but I need to use Contains, I will try a bit with the > 0 way, thanks a lot anyways will see what I can do

Comment: Hey there, 
Your answer is great!
Only one note: It is not necessary to suggest the user is attempting something obscure by asking this question.

Comment: @GabrielG I was not referring to the user, but to whoever would read this answer. I also explained why it would be obscure (and the limitation making it obscure). I also gave an example of legit (yet obscure) reason and an example. 
We are not here to do what's necessary to your eye. We are here to do what's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Person
WHERE CONTAINS((fName), 'John')
AND CONTAINS((sName), 'Doe');
```

But in your case you dont want to use 2 contains so:

Alternatively, you could add a new computed column with a full text index on it.

Add a column like this:

```
computedCol AS fName+ ' ' + sName
```

And create the full text index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Person(computedCol LANGUAGE 1033)
KEY INDEX pk_Person_yourPrimaryKeyName
```

Then you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Person
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'John AND Doe')
```

Hope it works.

Comment: So won't it return Jane Doe as well ? Or will it just look at John Doe ?

Comment: Didnt tried but it should look at John Doe because AND operator.